# Evaluating a list of python lambda functions only evaluates the last list element

Tags: python

I have a list of lambda functions I want to evaluate in order. I'm not sure why, but only the last function gets evaluated. Example below:

```
  >>> def f(x,z):
  ...     print "x=",x,", z=",z
  ... 
  >>> 
  >>> g = lambda x : f(x,13)
  >>> g(2)
  x= 2 , z= 13    # As expected
  >>> 
  >>> lst=[]
  >>> 
  >>> for i in range(0,5): 
  ...    lst.append(lambda x: f(x,i))
  ... 
  >>> print lst
  [<function <lambda> at 0x10341e2a8>, <function <lambda> at 0x10341e398>, <function <lambda> at 0x10341e410>, <function <lambda> at 0x10341e488>, <function <lambda> at 0x10341e500>]
  >>> 
  >>> for fn in lst:
  ...   fn(3)
  ... 
  x= 3 , z= 4 # z should be 0
  x= 3 , z= 4 # z should be 1
  x= 3 , z= 4 # z should be 2
  x= 3 , z= 4 # z should be 3
  x= 3 , z= 4 # as expected.
```

I think only the last one is getting executed, but not the others. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I had a vague feeling it was referring to the variable in global space, but I had no idea what to search for. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the use case for this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The lambda is just looking up the global value of 'i'.

Try the following instead:

```
for i in range(0,5):
  lst.append(lambda x, z=i: f(x,z))
```

Answer (score 2):

try using partial, works for me:

```
from functools import partial

def f(x,z):
    print "x=",x,", z=",z

lst = [ partial(f,z=i) for i in range(5) ]

for fn in lst:
    fn(3)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: I've never used this, and the post by bluepnume below looks easier to use. Cheers!

Comment: Actually this is a pretty good solution. It makes a lot of sense to use partials in this case.

Comment: thanks ;) I also personally prefer the list comprehension over the for/append approach

Answer (score 1):

Not a Python expert, but is it possible that Python is treating `i` in

```
lst.append(lambda x: f(x,i))
```

as a reference? Then, after the loop, `i` is equal to its last assigned value (4), and when the functions are called, they follow their `i` reference, find 4, and execute with that value.

Disclosure: probably nonsense.

Comment: It is! (From the link given by Jon Skeet above). Thanks!

Comment: You're close. The lambda function looks up `i` when it's called, and in the global scope `i` is equal to 4, given that that's the last value it was set to in the loop.