# Forcing a list out of a generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>>def change(x): 
...    x.append(len(x))
...    return x
>>>a=[]
>>>b=(change(a) for i in range(3))
>>>next(b)
[0]
>>>next(b)
[0,1]
>>>next(b)
[0,1,2]
>>>next(b)
Traceback ... StopIteration
>>>a=[]
>>>b=(change(a) for i in range(3))
>>>list(b) #expecting [[0],[0,1],[0,1,2]]
[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]
```

So I was just testing my understanding of generators and messing around with the command prompt and now I'm unsure if I actually understand how generators work.

Comment: Your problem is the scope. All elements in `b` refer to the same variable `a` (which is returned from the `change` function), so what you are seeing is just the final value, since all the outputs point to the same object. This has nothing to do with iterators, is a combination of _scope_ and how python handles _arguments in functions_.

Comment: Hey @Bit, so is it because when I do `list(b)` it essentially goes to `[a,a,a]` due to the function returning `a` 3 times in the for loop, and because `a` is `[0,1,2]` in the end that's why I'm seeing `[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]]`?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to read more, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059205/evaluating-a-list-of-python-lambda-functions-only-evaluates-the-last-list-elemen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6059205) is a question with the same issue (it uses lambdas, but the logic is the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all calls to `change(a)` return **the same object** (in this case, the object is the value of `a`), but this object is mutable and changes its value. An example of the same problem without using generators:

```
a = []
b = []
for i in range(3):
   a.append(len(a))
   b.append(a)
print b
```

If you want to avoid it, you need to make a copy of your object (for example, make `change` return `x[:]` instead of `x`).